# c# i have two List Boxes and 1 dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have two `ListBox`es and 1 `Dictionary` I want when I select a key from `Listbox1`  the value will be selected in `ListBox2`

```
Dictionary<string, string> f_list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 f_list.Add("First Shift", "Lauren");
 f_list.Add("Second Shift", "Jamey");
 f_list.Add("Third Shift", "Salem");
foreach (var t in f_list)
{
   listBox1.Items.Add(t.Key);
   listBox2.Items.Add(t.Value);
}

foreach (var t in f_list) {

  if (listBox1.selecteditem == t.Key) {

  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to select a key from `Listbox1` and select value in `ListBox2` then you should take key from `Listbox1` and take value from `ListBox2`

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: i cant figure how it will be select the value using 'setselected()'

Comment: You need to provide more context about your UI. Is this a WinForm or WPF app? If WPF, are you writing this in the code behind or following MVVM?

Comment: I don't know what the second `foreach` is for. You should use `ListBox1`'s `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event, and in that method look for its value, find the corresponding string in `f_list` and then assign that value to `ListBox2`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're more likely to get a useful answer to your question if you help your readers understand what you are trying to do and what you've tried so far.  You might find the advice in [ask] and [mcve] helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var t in f_list) {
   index = listBox2.FindString(t.Value,-1);
   if (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == t.Key)
   {
     listBox2.SetSelected(index, true);
   }
}
```

Comment: You are always trying to find every value even if it's not the selected one.

Comment: You are not taking advantage of having a `Dictionary`, and you keep repeating the process even after you have found the item. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me fix your code:

```
string lb1Value = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
if (f_list.ContainsKey(lb1Value))
{
    int index = listBox2.FindStringExact(f_list[lb1Value]);
    listBox2.SetSelected(index, true);
}
```

This code should go in `listBox1_OnSelectedIndexChanged()`.

The idea of using a dictionary is to directly access the element you need. You should only loop through it if you are looking for a specific value and not a key.